# Migrating old, low-quality question

Tags: support, questions, migration

I want to [purify my karma](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th). According to Help Center:

> Begin by fixing your existing posts

An here is the problem: some time ago I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23446224/high-level-architecture-for-android) on StackOverflow. It was downvoted because it was an off-topic question that should belong rather to [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/). Then I deleted this question.

I think that best solution now would be to undelete this question and migrate it to Software Recommendations. But:

- I don't have enough reputation vote for migrating the question
- I have question ban

But my hope wasn't lost. According to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work):

> You can also flag the question for moderator attention and request
>   that they migrate it for you. Simply explain in the reason which site
>   you want it to be migrated

I did so. Then I got response:

> declined - flags should only be used to make moderators aware of
>   content that requires their intervention

How can I purify my karma in this situation?

Comment: Are you sure that the guys on Software Rec would want it? The rule of thumb is *don't migrate crap*.

Comment: posts older than 60 days cannot be migrated under any circumstances.  And posts only rarely ever get migrated to Beta sites, so migration would be inappropriate for 2 reasons.  Generally speaking, 1 bad post won't get you banned, so you can have one laying around.  Worry about your other posts.

Comment: migration to circumvent suspension / question ban at target site [would be blocked](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102293/block-migration-if-user-is-suspended-question-blocked-at-destination)

Comment: So, there is nothing I can do with this question?

Comment: @slugster Well, I don't know whether it is crap or not. But this is what asking questions is about.

Comment: @Kao Keep in mind I didn't mean that in a bad way - but it is something that a mod would consider before migrating your question (frequently they will ask the mods of the target site if they want the question, and frequently the receiving mods will decline the migration). Don't be too concerned about it, at least you are taking the time to do something about it (many don't).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That question is not salvageable. And even if it was, a migrated question isn't gonna look any better on your record than one you deleted. Leave it be.

You have 5 other questions, only one of which is deleted. You're much better off focusing on them. The edits you made [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22960589/which-package-structure-is-more-cohessive-for-pairs-of-objects) resulted in undeletion which lifted the quality-ban for the time being - clean up the rest of your questions, and you'll be a lot better off.

Comment: Ban is lifted. I feel purified. Thanks!